# How to place links over "overflow: auto;" area while hover?

Tags: html, css

I've coded horizontal navigation that generally works as expected. If you hover a link, this link gets blurry. Unfortunately, the blurring effect is cut off, from the top, and the bottom. I would be able to fix this issue with more `padding-top` and `padding-bottom`, but the navigation should be just a narrow strip.

Is there a way to place links while hovering over the navigation? Like with `position: absolute;` maybe? I tried add `position: absolute;` and `z-index: 1;`. Unfortunately, the position in the line gets lost.

Is there a way to keep the position in the line? With something like `display: inline;`?

Here is the code:

```css
html {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 80px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: default;
}

nav {
  margin-top: 30px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: relative;
}

nav span:hover {
  filter: blur(20px);
  /* position: absolute; */
  /* z-index: 1; */
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <span>One</span>
  <span>Two</span>
  <span>Three</span>
  <span>Four</span>
  <span>Five</span>
  <span>Six</span>
  <span>Seven</span>
</nav>

<div>Some other text. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</div>
```

The navigation should be horizontally scrollable. Nothing else. The blur effect value should be `20px`.

Comment: you should provide some space above the navigation, like a padding-top to the body element

Comment: Yes, I could make some padding around. But then this navigation "tripe" is pretty high. And I need this space for other content ;)

Comment: From answers to your question it is obvious to me you would be well served to add some much needed detail to your question. For instance, you say you want to have horizontal navigation, but from your stylesheet it is evident you already have it? Second, how is the area not large enough -- in both axis, or only one, and if so which one? Last, I wouldn't use `*` and applying style to everything -- you probably want to rely on CSS's natural cascading and just apply font size etc, at least, to `body` instead. As for padding etc -- I guess it should go for some content in `nav`?

Comment: Well, experimenting with your snippet looks like your only option -- because the [specification](https://drafts.fxtf.org/filter-effects/#FilterProperty) is vague on whether a filter may or may not paint outside element's [border] box -- is to use padding (in both axis) for your span elements to give each link some surrounding space the filter can effectively use so the blur effect doesn't look cut off. The extra padding doesn't have to necessarily make for a "thick" strip -- you may still be able to have a wide and thin (in vertical axis) navigation "bar".

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
nav {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: relative;
}
```

To this:

```
nav {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-y: visible;    // this is changed
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There should be also other content on this page. So this does not help me ...

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 80px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: default;
}

nav {
  padding: 10px 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: relative;
}

nav span:hover {
  filter: blur(20px);
  /* position: absolute; */
  /* z-index: 1; */
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <span>One</span>
  <span>Two</span>
  <span>Three</span>
  <span>Four</span>
  <span>Five</span>
  <span>Six</span>
  <span>Seven</span>
</nav>

<div>Some other text. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</div>
```

Comment: The navigation should be horizontally scrollable. Nothing else.

Comment: you can decrease the blur to 13px !